# C++ - binary '=': no operator found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I am trying to learn C++, so I am very new.

I am attempting to write something that takes a vector and writes the contents to a file:

```
int AsciiConvert::TextToAscii(const std::string file_content, fs::directory_entry entry)
{
    //int test_text_char;

    std::vector<int> temp_text_int;

    std::ofstream output_file(".\\Output\\" + entry.path().filename().string(), std::ios::out);

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < file_content.length(); i++)
    {
        temp_text_int.push_back(file_content[i]);
        /*output_file << test_text_char;*/
    }

    //std::cout << temp_text_int.begin() << " " << temp_text_int.end() << std::endl;

    std::copy(temp_text_int.begin(), temp_text_int.end(), output_iterator);

    output_file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

However, when i compile this i get a C2679 error code (based around the std::copy line):

```
C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) AsciiConvert    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xutility    3330
```

Any help would be appreciated, i feel that i'm so close to making this work!

Comment: `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>` Why `std::string`?

Comment: What this code supposed to do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: std::string becuase the file contains text? If you feel that is wrong please let me know what it should be and why. Open minded and wanted to learn :)

Comment: This is a function to convert text to Ascii, there was a unique issue a colleague had that i was trying to look into.

Comment: Prefer to pass `std::string` by reference or `const` reference if the parameter is not modified.  Otherwise the compiler makes a copy before passing to your function.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You've made this stuff too complicated:

```cpp
void AsciiConvert::writeCharsCodesToFile(const std::string& text, fs::path path)
{
    std::ostream f{path};
    writeCharsCodes(text, f);
}

std::ostream& AsciiConvert::writeCharsCodes(const std::string& text, std::ostream& out)
{
    for (auto ch : text) {
       out << static_cast<int>(ch) << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}

// or if you prefer stream iterators:
std::ostream& AsciiConvert::writeCharsCodes(const std::string& text, std::ostream& out)
{
    std::copy(text.begin(), text.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>{out, "\n"});
    return out;
}
```